# Loading exported file to view

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I use *JasperReports* library 5.6.0

I tire programing:
VIEWER (JRViewer) PDF ---> XML ---> PDF VIEWER (JRViewer)

1. step - export generated raport view to xml file
2. step -  exported file xml convert to pdf and showing JRViewer

But i have problem with step 2,

```
// file is variable xml file generated from step 1

    JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(file);
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(b)); 

    JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);
```

I got the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:323)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:284)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:273)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:202)
    at pl.opencare.wydruki.PrintFunctions$1.actionPerformed(PrintFunctions.java:460)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code step 1:

```
// p is my report
JasperPrint p = ..........

StringBuffer xml = new StringBuffer();

JRXmlExporter xmlExporter = new JRXmlExporter();
xmlExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, p);
xmlExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STRING_BUFFER, xml);
xmlExporter.exportReport();

File file = File.createTempFile("temp", ".xml"); 
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
bw.write(xml.toString());
bw.close();
```

The file is not empty i can show it tempolary directory.

in step 2 sbove error java.lang.NullPointerException ,netbeans show line

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this error could come up, is if the *file* used in JRXmlLoader.load(*file*) was somehow wrong (most likely empty or otherwise not correct .jrxml file). If that's the case, your not-described "step one" must contain errors.

@Answer with details (I think editing the question would be more appropiate format of giving more details to question)

And there is a problem. I didn't know, that what you had was JasperPrint instance,  which represents already filled report. According to [JRXmlExported Documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXmlExporter.html) exporting it creates .jrpxml and can be parsed back again as JasperPrint instance using  [JRPrintXmlLoader](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/xml/JRPrintXmlLoader.html). Trying to load filled in report as JasperDesign to fill it again might produce errors (and apparently it does). Is there any particular reason why you can't operate on .jrxml file or JasperDesign instance used to create the report?